# find and replace a string in a file using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I have a file `odbc.ini` with the following text

```
[DB2DB]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB2DB DB2 ODBC Database
Database=DB2DB
[EBAICIMS]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB ALIAS 
Database=EBAICIMS
[EBAIPDMD]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB ALIAS 
Database=EBAIPDMD
[EBAIRELS]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB ALIAS 
Database=EBAIRELS
[POLICYD]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB2 alias to connect
Database=POLICYD
[JDCUCCD]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB2DB DB2 ODBC Database
Database=JDCUCCD
[POLICYQ]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB2 alias to connect
Database=POLICYQ
[POLICYM]
DRIVER=libdb2Wrapper.so
Description=DB2 alias to connect
Database=POLICYM
```

I am trying to replace `libdb2Wrapper.so` in this file with `/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so`

I am trying to do it in a single line using sed but it isn't working.
I used 
`sed 's/libdb2Wrapper.so/~/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so/g' -i odbc.ini`
I also tried with backslashes as escape characters but it didn't work. Maybe I am doing something wrong with the use of escape characters.
Please help.

Comment: In what way did sed not work? Did it fail to print anything out? Did it print an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the need to backslash slashes, use a different separator for sed:

```
sed -i~ -e 's=libdb2Wrapper.so=~/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so=g' odbc.ini
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think i made a mistake with the escape characters. I am using this now `sed -i 's=libdb2Wrapper.so=/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so=g' odbcLAB.ini`.

Answer (score 0):

While you don't need to show every attempt to solve your problem, as you realize it is probably escaping `/` chars that is your problem, best to include that attempt in your question.

Try

```
sed -i '@libdb2Wrapper.so@\~/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so@g' odbc.ini
```

You probably need to esacpe the `~` char as it is usually means "all that was matched"

Some older `sed`s get confused if they don't see `/` as the first character, but most will understand ans escaped first char, i.e.

```
sed -i '\@libdb2Wrapper.so@\~/home/inst8/sqllib/libdb2o.so@g' odbc.ini
```

Finally, note that you can use about any character as the initial reg-ex wrapper, just make sure it's not in either your target or replacement text.

IHTH